# Nextjs device detection

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I want to write a website with different mobile and PC versions with Nextjs. I've looked at many resources on the internet but none of them have been helpful enough. I think I need to use the @folder structure. I tried a little with useEffect, but due to the working timing, the other version also appears on the page, although it is instantaneous. What path should I follow?

As an example, I can give amazon's site, it loads differently depending on the login from pc and mobile.

```
    import "../styles/reset.css";
    import "../styles/globals.css";
    import { Inter } from "next/font/google";

    const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

    export const metadata = {
      title: "e-commerce",
      description: "e-commerce website",
    };

    export default function RootLayout({ mobile, desktop }) {
      return (
        <html lang="en">
          <body className={inter.className}>
            {isMobile ? mobile : desktop}
          </body>
        </html>
      );
    }
```